# How am I able to take a screenshot of the dev tool in the current browser?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, google-chrome-devtools

`Awesome screenshot` is a great tool and I'am using it for google chrome.

Now, I would like to shot the devtool too which is part of the google chrome browser, but using `Awesome screenshot` is not possible.

Look to this image

Are there other plugins/browser (firefox/firebug) able to make this job?

Thanks.

P.S.

The goal of Awesome screenshot is not to make just a screenshot, but to share very easly this sreenshot in the web with other web developers for example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is "how am I able to take a screenshot of the dev tool in the current browser?", you could just do a simple Print screen and paste it into photoshop or fireworks.

Comment: The goal of Awesome screenshot is not to make just a screenshot, but to share very easly this sreenshot in the web with other web developers for example.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the comment about the title.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome allows to make screenshots of webpages. Bookmarks panel / developer tools window are not part of a webpage so they won't appear on a screenshot.

There is a brand new [developer tools API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devtools.html) that allows to extend developer tools panel. It may be possible to create an extension that does screenshot from inside the devtools window then combines it with a screenshot of a webpage. But it seems complicated.

If possible, simply use some external tool to do a screenshot of whole browser window.

Comment: The goal of Awesome screenshot is not to make just a screenshot, but to share very easly this sreenshot in the web with other web developers for example.

Comment: The bookmarks panel and developer tools window are too webpages! You can inspect elements in them, even. :D though I doubt the APIs let you access their DOMs.